# Form submition don't work

Tags: 7, forms

I will build a form for register new team on drupal 7 website.

In my custom module i use this code :

tournament.module :

```
function tournament_menu() {
    $items['tournament/newteam'] = array(
        'title' => 'Créer une nouvelle équipe',
        'page callback' => 'form_newteam',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'file' => 'form_tournament.inc',
    );
}
```

form_tournament.inc :

```
function form_newteam ($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['description'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#title' => 'Créer une nouvelle équipe'
    );

    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );
    $form['name']['name_team'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Nom de l\'équipe',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => "Entrez le nom de votre équipe.",
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 25,
    );
    $form['name']['tag_team'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Tag de l\'équipe',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => "Entrez le tag de votre équipe (version courte du nom de votre     équipe ex : 'FrR').",
        '#size' => 4,
        '#maxlength' => 4,
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Créer',
    );

    $form['contact'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Contact'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );
    $form['contact']['contact_email_team'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Email de contact de l\'équipe',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => "Entrez l'email de contact de la team.",
        '#size' => 20,
    );    
    $form['contact']['contact_name_team'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Nom du contact',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => "Entrez le nom du contact de l'équipe.",
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 64,
   );

    [...]

    return $form;
}

function form_newteam_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $syntaxe_email = '#^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$#';

    if (!preg_match($syntaxe_email, $email)) {
        form_set_error('contact_email_team', "Entrez une adresse email valide !");
    }    
}

function form_newteam_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    drupal_set_message('OK : team : @team, tag : @tag, email : @email, contact : @contact, site_web : @site, logo : @filename. ',
        array(
            '@team' => $form_state['name']['name_team'],
            '@tag' => $form_state['name']['tag_team'],
            '@email' => $form_state['contact']['contact_email_team'],                
        )
    );
}
```

This form appears correctly, but when i submit it, nothing is happening...

Any idea ?

Thank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drupal_get_form has to be called to render a correct form.

Alter the hook_menu definition to this:

```
function tournament_menu() {
    $items['tournament/newteam'] = array(
        'title' => t('Créer une nouvelle équipe'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('form_newteam')
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'file' => 'form_tournament.inc',
    );
}
```